# Recurring events in Fullcalendar version 6 using rrule

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, rrule, fullcalendar-6

I'm trying to figure out recurring events in fullcalendar version 6 using rrule but it is not working. I need to do recurring events every week on specific days, every month, and yearly. I can't figure out what is wrong neither is shows me any error in console.

```
  calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        // Event handlers
        eventClick: function(info) {
            var eventObj = info.event;
            populateAndShowModal(eventObj, eventObj.extendedProps.procedure);
        },
        eventReceive: function(info) {
            var eventObj = info.event;
            populateAndShowModal(eventObj, eventObj.title);
        },

        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        droppable: true,
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
        displayEventTime: false,
        slotLabelInterval: {
            minutes: 30
        },
        slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
        slotMaxTime: '19:00:00',
        eventTimeFormat: {
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12: false,
        },
        height: "auto",
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next,custom2',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'custom1,resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
        },
        editable: true,
        resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Staff',
        resources: [{
            id: 6,
            title: "New",
        }, {
            id: 211,
            title: "Test",
        }],
        events: [{
            title: "SiH|97155|Processed|208|97155",
            duration: '39:00',
            resourceId: 211,
            assignedToName: "Matt Randall",
            procedure: "97155",
            color: "#00ffca",
            rrule: {
                freq: rrule.RRule.WEEKLY,
                interval: 2,
                byweekday: [rrule.RRule.WED],
                dtstart: '2024-03-13T08:00:00'
            }
        }]
    });
    calendar.render();
```

[image: picture of calendar]

Comment: `rrule` isn't part of the core FullCalendar functionality, but needs a plugin - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin

Comment: Are you quite sure there are no errors? When I used your event data it produced an error in rrule, which suggests to me that you probably got the rrule event syntax wrong - check the console in this demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BaEzvJx ..it reports `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'n')` in the rrule.min.js file. This line: `byweekday: [rrule.RRule.WED]` of your rule seems to be the problem, because if we comment it out, the error goes away. Check the rrule docs and try to express your intention correctly according to the documented syntax.

Comment: Glancing at the docs (https://github.com/jkbrzt/rrule), I expect it should be `rrule.RRule.WE` (without the D - all the other constants are two-letters). And indeed that works: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEZOVZY . Downvoted as unclear (for failing to report error information accurately), and voted to close as a typo since it's a trivial mistake which could have been solved by reading the documentation more carefully. If you're kind enough to save the community the review and voting time, you could just delete the question yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was missing js which connects full calendar and rrule plugin. It is working now as I have code like this.

```
 calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    // Event handlers
    eventClick: function(info) {
        var eventObj = info.event;
        populateAndShowModal(eventObj, eventObj.extendedProps.procedure);
    },
    eventReceive: function(info) {
        var eventObj = info.event;
        populateAndShowModal(eventObj, eventObj.title);
    },

    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    droppable: true,
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
    displayEventTime: false,
    slotLabelInterval: {
        minutes: 30
    },
    slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
    slotMaxTime: '19:00:00',
    eventTimeFormat: {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: false,
    },
    height: "auto",
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next,custom2',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'custom1,resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Staff',
    resources: [{
        id: 6,
        title: "New",
    }, {
        id: 211,
        title: "Test",
    }],
    events: [{
        title: "SiH|97155|Processed|208|97155",
        duration: '39:00',
        resourceId: 211,
        assignedToName: "Matt Randall",
        procedure: "97155",
        color: "#00ffca",
        rrule: {
            freq: "weekly",
            interval: 2,
            byweekday: ["mo"],
            dtstart: '2024-03-13T08:00:00'
        }
    }]
});
calendar.render();
```

Comment: <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.10/index.global.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrule@2.6.4/dist/es5/rrule.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/rrule@6.1.11/index.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.30.1/moment.min.js"></script>